# Does/Should [election-requirements] include appointed offices?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the main site there is a [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/86516/42309) about requirements to become Prime Minister of India. I've added the tag [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements) but I am increasingly unsure about that edit.

On the one hand, the Prime Minister of India is not elected but appointed by the President, so technically [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements) would not apply.

On the other hand, the practical effect of these requirements isn't any different from the requirements to hold an elected office.

Is [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements) applicable to the question above?
Do we need to change the tag-wiki or create a new tag for requirements to be appointed to a political office?

Comment: It could be renamed to 'office-requirements', I guess. I'm not sure if it's worth the hassle though. PMs and so forth are elected internally by a party in some way.

Answer (score 3):

I see no problem with using the [election-requirements](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election-requirements) tag for this case.

Items 2 through 4, below, identify election requirements that must be met for a Prime Minister.

From [How Is The Prime Minister Of India Elected?](https://www.india.com/lok-sabha-elections-2019-india/how-is-the-prime-minister-of-india-elected-read-to-know-about-qualifications-powers-3600843/)

Here are the qualifications or eligibility criteria of the Prime Minister of India:

2. He or she must either be a member of the Lok Sabha (Lower House or House of the people) or the Rajya Sabha (Upper House).
3. If the candidate is a member of the Lok Sabha, he or she should be at least 25 years old. If the candidate is a Rajya Sabha member, then he or she must be 30 years of age.
4. The President may appoint a person as the Prime Minister who is a member of neither of the Parliamentary House. In such a case, the selected candidate must become a member of either the Lok Sabha or the Rajya Sabha within a period of six months.